# Realm Android. Как по выбору скрывать один из типов данных

Tags: java, android, json, realm

У меня есть модель в которой описано множество тип данных. 
Эту модель я использую по разному, в одном случае я её использую для того, чтоб помещать json файл в модель реалма и преобразовывать realm модель в Json файл. Хотел бы узнать, как можно при разных запросах скрывать один из типов данных.

Например:
В Реалмовской модели есть тип данных (Date start_date) при преобразовании с Json в Realm я хочу чтоб он был, а вот из Realm в Json не хочу его использовать, но и писать вторую такую же модель без использования (Date start_date) не хочу.

Есть ли способ, с помощью которого можно не впихивать поле (start_date) в запрос на отправку.

- ко всему, когда я делаю запрос, я отправляю Body в который ложу модель и сериализую.

P.S. Буду раз помощи.

```
happApi.createEvent(event).enqueue(new Callback<Event>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<Event> call, Response<Event> response) {

                Log.d("HAPP_API", String.valueOf(response.code()));
                Log.d("HAPP_API", response.message());

                if (response.isSuccessful()) {

                    Event event = response.body();

                    User user = App.getCurrentUser();
                    if (event.getAuthor().getId().equals(user.getId())) {
                        event.setAuthor(user);
                    }

                    Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
                    realm.beginTransaction();
                    realm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(event);
                    realm.commitTransaction();
                    realm.close();

                    Intent intent = new Intent(BroadcastIntents.EVENTCREATE_REQUEST_OK);
                    String eventId = event.getId();
                    intent.putExtra("event_id", eventId);
                    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(App.getContext()).sendBroadcast(intent);
                } else {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(BroadcastIntents.EVENTCREATE_REQUEST_FAIL);
                    intent.putExtra("CODE", response.code());
                    showRequestError(response);
                    intent.putExtra("MESSAGE", response.message());
                    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(App.getContext()).sendBroadcast(intent);
                }

                Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
                realm.beginTransaction();
                Event oldEvent = realm.where(Event.class).equalTo("id", eventId).findFirst();
                oldEvent.deleteFromRealm();
                realm.commitTransaction();
                realm.close();
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<Event> call, Throwable t) {

                Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
                realm.beginTransaction();
                Event oldEvent = realm.where(Event.class).equalTo("id", eventId).findFirst();
                oldEvent.deleteFromRealm();
                realm.commitTransaction();
                realm.close();

                Intent intent = new Intent(BroadcastIntents.EVENTCREATE_REQUEST_FAIL);
                Toast.makeText(App.getContext(), t.getLocalizedMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                intent.putExtra("MESSAGE", t.getLocalizedMessage());
                LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(App.getContext()).sendBroadcast(intent);
            }
```

Comment: Боюсь что нормального решения нет. Т.е. вам придётся вручную исключать ненужные поля из полученного JSON.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб не подскажете как это делается? Ответ дополнил.

Comment: Ну, при получении ничего делать не надо, а при отправке, после формирования JSON из объекта реалма вам надо из JSONObject удалить пару ключ-значение по ключу прежде чем передавать этот JSON серверу